# Redirect 301 www.my-site.com/page/n to www.my-site.com/

Tags: redirect, htaccess

How to make redirection on WordPress site with .htaccess to redirect this:

http://www.my-site.com/page/n

to home page:

http://www.my-site.com/

I do not wish to list previous post on site on first page of site, I removed paginated links from bottom of index.php but it is possible to open those pages typing address in browser location bar, or to find already indexed links by search engines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though what you're asking is to redirect /page/n to the homepage, this can be accomplished with the RedirectMatch directive.

So:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/(.*) http://www.my-site.com/
```

would redirect all traffic from /page/n to the homepage.

Comment: Will this redirect just http://www.my-site.com/page/n to home page of site or it might redirect category, archive or any other paged url to site home? Any possible issues with it?

Comment: This will redirect all URL's after /page/ to home.  You probably just want to use redirect 301 and specify exact pages if you don't want to redirect all.

Comment: How I can specify all possible home paged URLs like www.my-site.com/page/n in .htaccess to prevent redirecting any category paged links like www.my-site.com/category/name/page/n to home page?

Comment: I just find a bug in your redirection rule above. It also redirect search result URL like this site.com/page/2?s=keyword to site.com/2?s=keyword (first page of search results). Can you fix that? Thanks @HowardE

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` is ok but I often like the convenience of using a plugin for this stuff. I like [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) most, it also supports regular expressions.

The regexp `^/page/(.*)` will match stuff like `page/n` and it won't match `category/name/page/n`. You might want to learn [more about regexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) if needed.

Comment: So, it is safe to use it just to redirect www.my-site.com/page/n to www.my-site.com/, it will not redirect any other pages to home page?

Comment: Yeah just give it a try, either with `.htaccess` or the Redirection plugin. Test it and see if it works as expected.